# Betta losing colour

Tags: fish

My Betta is losing its colour from its head. This seems to be progressing daily. Please see pics. What is the cause and is there any cure?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How old is your Betta? Colour change is perfectly normal in goldfish (as long as there's no other sign of illness, like slime) but I can't say for bettas. My yellow goldfish is going white at about 2 years old - it'd look similar to this (I'm not worried about her).

Comment: @Pam i do not think it is normal for bettas to change colour,in the carp family colour changes do happen(orange or yellow koi  do often change colour to white overnight before they change slowly back to the original colour)